# In numeral system with base $c$ the sum of two non-zero numbers $aba_(c)$ and $bab_(c)$ equals $xyxy_(c)$. Find all values of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

As the title says I have to find all possible values of $a$ and $b$ when given the base $c$.
I don't really know how to approach this problem. I found out that it's true when $a+b=c+1$.
Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should include the question in the body as well as the title. I prefer the notation $aba_c$ mean digits $aba$ in base $c$ but you can use the { and } symbols to format $aba_{(c)}$ if you prefer. What have you tried so far? How did you add $aba_c$ and $bab_c$? What system of equations did that lead to?

Comment: The first thing I suggest is writing out $aba_{c} = ac^2 + bc + a$, etc. Then adding the expressions together and seeing what you get.

Comment: If $c = 10$, then $5 + 6 = 10 + 1$, but $565 + 656 = 1221$, which is not in the form $xyxy_{10}$.